# Disconnected disk still in mount list

Tags: linux, mount, fat32

I have mounted a FAT32 usb disk on `~/mnt/porco` with `mount -o umask=022,uid=1000,gid=1000 /dev/sdj2 mnt/porco`, and then unmounted it with `umount ~/mnt/porco` and `umount -lf ~/mnt/porco`. `umount` finished without any errors, but when I disconnected the physical disk, it still stayed on the list of mountpoints when I run `mount`. It doesn't show up anywhere else, but when I do it again and again, I get many unexistent devices mounted on the same point:

```
/dev/sdj2 on /home/filip/mnt/porco type vfat (rw,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=ascii,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/sdk2 on /home/filip/mnt/porco type vfat (rw,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=ascii,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/sdk2 on /home/filip/mnt/porco type vfat (rw,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=ascii,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/sdl2 on /home/filip/mnt/porco type vfat (rw,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=ascii,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/sdm2 on /home/filip/mnt/porco type vfat (rw,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=ascii,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/sdn2 on /home/filip/mnt/porco type vfat (rw,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=ascii,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro)
```

The only way I was able to get rid of those was by restarting the computer. Is there a way to remove those entries? I can still mount another disk in the directory and there seems to be no damage to the disk. I just use a program, which gets device based on mountpoint, and gets pointed to a device that doesn't exist, because it was mounted there before.

Comment: First check what's mounted on `/home/filip/mnt/porco` after a restart before running `mount`. Then perform the `mount` and check the differences. Then `umount` and check the differences. My guess is that those mounts your show were already there, or were created by different apps/commands. Then even `umount` command will remove one of those mounts (according to the order they were mounted) until you remove all the mounts that existed on this point.